# Conflict with the font size in webview - Android

Tags: android, html, android-webview

In my application I am showing a long text, and to customize it my way (justification, bold, italics, underline, colors) I show via a `WebView`. The problem I have is that when testing the activity in a tablet letters `WebView` not appear the right size, are very small, and when I change the orientation of the `tablet` (sometimes the first, or after doing this several times ) WebView updates and letters are the correct size.

Below I give you the codes I'm using:

main/assets/sometext.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf8">
    <style>

        @font-face {
        font-family: 'times';
        src: url('times.ttf');
        }

        @font-face {
        font-family: 'timesbd';
        src: url('timesbd.ttf');
        }

        html, div {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

        h1 {font-family: 'times';}

        {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        }

        body {
        font-family: timesbd;
        font-size: 11pt;
        text-align: justify;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">

<p class="HTMLPARAGUIAPAA" style="margin-top:0cm"><u>Instrucciones</u>:
    Seleccione la <u>mejor</u> respuesta para cada uno de los ejercicios.
    <o:p></o:p>
</p>

<p class="HTMLPARAGUIAPAA" style='margin: 0; padding: 0'>Cada uno de los siguientes
    enunciados tiene uno o dos espacios en blanco. Cada espacio indica que se ha omitido
    una palabra o frase. Debajo de los enunciados hay cinco opciones señaladas con
    las letras A, B, C, D y E. Usted debe seleccionar la opción que, al insertarse
    en el enunciado, complete <u>mejor</u> su significado.
    <o:p></o:p>
</p>
```

layout.xml:

```
<WebView
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:id="@+id/wb_examen_evaluacion_instrucciones_por_seccion"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp" />
```

java:

```
wb_instrucciones_por_seccion = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb_examen_evaluacion_instrucciones_por_seccion);

//INSTRUCCIONES
        wb_instrucciones_por_seccion.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(wb_instrucciones_por_seccion, url);

                        wb_instrucciones_por_seccion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        wb_instrucciones_por_seccion.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sometext.html");
        wb_instrucciones_por_seccion.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        wb_instrucciones_por_seccion.setScrollBarStyle(View.GONE);
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Examen_evaluacion"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/titulo_examen_evaluacion_activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="EXAMEN_EVALUACION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

What can I do to display the text size I want from the beginning?

Comment: I guess it's because you are declaring your size in `pt` all the textsizes will be differently according to each device.

Comment: But, when I start the activity the size is X (small) on portrait, and when I change the orientation to landscape the size is Y (12pt), and finally when I change the orientation again to portrait the text size is Y (12pt)

Comment: That's strange. Have you considered using `dimensions` for your activity then ? (instead of WebView, use an activity)?